# User registration; validate email but don't activate automatically

Tags: users, registration

is it possible to have the public registration form validate the users Email, but still require manual activation by a system administrator?

There's [User Registration - Keep as inactive until verified by admin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5216/user-registration-keep-as-inactive-until-verified-by-admin) which I think will stop a clicked email confirmation link from activating the user...

but from what I can tell Craft's "email confirmation" is really just an "activate user via link"; so it's not really confirming the validity of the email nor storing that confirmation anywhere; it's just activating the user. Is that right or am I mis-understanding it?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

I think the approach [Johannes posted](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/5223/125) as an answer to the question you linked to is a good one.

- Let the user activate the account via email. It makes sure the address exists and he has access to it, because he can't guess the activation URL without the mail.
- This activation only makes him become a member of a Users Group without any permissions at all (e.g. 'unverifiedUsers'). To restrict front end access do something like this:

  ```
  {% if currentUser.isInGroup('unverifiedUsers') %}
      <p>You don't have access rights. Please wait until an admin verifies you account. Thank you!</p>
  {% else %}
      {% include 'partial' %}
  {% endif %}
  ```
- Then let an admin do the manual verification: add the user to a group with the permissions you want.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not practical for my use case; I've a plugin that creates an entry on activation - I don't want that happening unless the user is also verified; so the verification needs to happen prior to the activation. With the Group approach, the page would be created prior to the admin vetting the user.

Comment: @MattWilcox you could rewrite the plugin and listen to `users.onSaveUser` instead of `users.onActivateUser` events and conditionally create that "first entry" if the user is a) in the right user group (not 'unverifiedUsers' any more) and b) no entry by that user exists.